# Having trouble creating an if formula in excel that will produce a Value rather than what is being typed into the quotes

Tags: excel

=IF(Delivered!G10>0, "Complete", "=D10-Counts!F10") this is the formula that I have so far. The first part of the formula is fine it is the second part. If the value is less than 0 I would like the formula to produce a value instead of it saying what is in the quotes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do not put it in quotes and remove the `=`:

```
=IF(Delivered!G10>0, "Complete", D10-Counts!F10)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, but now I have a new question. I want the word complete to be green when it shows up, is this possible?

Comment: 1. please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  2. New question = new post. but before you do, look into conditional formatting.  You can set the cell that when the value in that cell is `complete` it will turn green.